# GAE JDO Empty Query Result

Tags: google-app-engine, jdo, rpc

I'm putting together a simple GWT, GAE, JDO application.  To start with, I'm attempting to store a table of Cat Records.  I managed to get the RPC mechanism to work in my call to save the data (see setCOTDCats() below).  The RPC call is successful as far as I can tell.  However, when I try to read the values back (see getCOTDCats() below), it too seems to work except that it returns an empty result.

Clearly either the save didn't work, or the read didn't, but I don't know how to tell which isn't working.

I'm a GAE and JDO Newbie.  Please take this into account with any responses.

Thanks

No Snark Please

```
@Override
public Cat[] getCOTDCats()
{
    final List<Cat> catList = new ArrayList<Cat>();
    final PersistenceManager pm = getPersistenceManager();
    try
    {
        final Query q = pm.newQuery(CatRecord.class);
        q.setOrdering("COTDDate");
        final List<CatRecord> catRecords = (List<CatRecord>) q.execute();
        for (CatRecord catRecord: catRecords)
        {
            final Cat cat = catRecord.getCat();
            catList.add(cat);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        pm.close();
    }
    final Cat[] result = catList.toArray(new Cat[0]);
    return result;
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see org.catadoptionteam.catserve.client.AnimalDataService#setCOTDCats(org.catadoptionteam.catserve.shared.Cat[])
 */
@Override
public void setCOTDCats(Cat[] cat)
{
    final List<CatRecord> catList = new ArrayList<CatRecord>();
    for (Cat c: cat)
    {
        final CatRecord catRecord = new CatRecord(c);
        catList.add(catRecord);
    }
    final PersistenceManager pm = getPersistenceManager();
    try
    {
        pm.makePersistentAll(catList);
    }
    finally
    {
        pm.close();
    }
}

private static PersistenceManager getPersistenceManager()
{
    final PersistenceManager result = Persister.getPersistenceManager();
    return result;
}

public enum Persister
{
    INSTANCE;

    private static final PersistenceManagerFactory pmfInstance = 
        JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory("transactions-optional");

    public static PersistenceManager getPersistenceManager()
    {
        final PersistenceManager result = pmfInstance.getPersistenceManager();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: I spent today trying different things.  I seem to be getting data back now, but it's incorrect.  I removed some of my fields in my PersistenceCapable CatRecord.  I was wondering if one (or more) of my data types are not valid to use?  I'm using Key, String, Date, boolean, Text, and an enum I defined.

Comment: The local_db viewer tells you if the save worked. The log also tells you lots of things

Comment: It seems to be working better now.  I'm not sure what went wrong.  I found that deleting the war/WEB-INF/appengine-generated/* files seemed to help.  I don't know if this is a good idea.  I only found this out by trial and error.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the problem lies in the way you handle the PersistenceManager. Define a class PMF.java as follows:

```
import javax.jdo.JDOHelper;
import javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactory;

public final class PMF {
    private static final PersistenceManagerFactory pmfInstance = JDOHelper
            .getPersistenceManagerFactory("transactions-optional");

    private PMF() {
    }

    public static PersistenceManagerFactory get() {
        return pmfInstance;
    }
}
```

Then, when you want to get access to the PersistenceManager, you should call:

```
PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
```

In addition, all your models (Cat in your example) should be defined with JDO. For detailed information check at: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, I added more detail above regarding what I did with the PersistenceManager.  Seems the same to me.

Comment: I think I have defined CatRecord and Cat as @PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION, detachable="true")
public final class CatRecord
{
@PrimaryKey
@Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
private Key id;
...

Comment: I can post more code if it helps.  Is there a database browser tool that would allow me see if the write works?

Comment: The local db viewer: http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin Note that the port may be different based on your configuration.